# PID loop rate versus response time

Tags: pid-controller

If I have a system with a response time of T milliseconds, how fast should I run a digital PID loop ie what is the minimum frequency that the lop should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$T_0 \leq(\dfrac{1}{6}÷\dfrac{1}{15})T_{95}\$

\$T_{95}\$...95% of the step-response settling time

Author: V.Bobal et al., Digital Self-tuning Controllers

EDIT:

Let's say: \$y=(1-e^{-t/T})\$, where y is the output step response. Now, $$0.95=(1-e^{-T_{95}/T})$$ $$-\dfrac{T_{95}}{T}=ln(0.05)$$ $$\dfrac{T_{95}}{T}\approx3$$

This gives:
\$T_0 \leq(\dfrac{1}{2}÷\dfrac{1}{5})\cdot T\$

Comment: Are those brackets in the correct position?

Comment: What do you mean? 1/6 to 1/15 of T95. Or from 0.166 to 0.0666 T95.